# Unable to execute all statements in code block using threading

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy

I am trying to read a number of files in a folder and process them simultaneously using threads.

The structure of the program is like this :

```
// Assuming there are 5 files in the directory

// creating the threads
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
ExecutorCompletionService service = new ExecutorCompletionService(pool)

directory.listFiles().each { eachFile ->
   service.submit(new FileReader(eachFile, param2))
}


// the FileReader class
class FileReader implements Callable {
    File file
    String param
    FileReader(File file, String param){
        this.file = file
        this.param = param
    }

   Object call(){
      LOG.info("Processing file" + filePath)
      ConfigInfo configInfo = new ConfigInfo()
  configInfo.setFilePath(filePath);
  configInfo.setReaderUid(readerUid);
  configInfo.setPatternsMap(patternsMap);
  new LogfileDataProcessor(configObject, param).processFileContent()
   }

}
```

The call method here creates another object and calls a method on it.

But oddly enough the program terminates after executing some lines in the call method(it does not reach the final statement in it). I am confused here. Can someone throw some light on what is happening. Please help me

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I see you made an edit.  Can we expect to see an SSCCE any time soon?

Comment: i have edited the call() method. The program when run prints the logger comment but it does not seem to create the LogfileDataProcessor object and call the processFileContent method. Hope that gives a better idea

Comment: *"Hope that gives a better idea"* So, that would be a 'no' to my question?  (shrugs) Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your program wait for thread to be finished. You can use CountDounLatch for example for this:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numberOfFilesInDirectory);

directory.listFiles().each { eachFile ->
   service.submit(new FileReader(eachFile, param2))
}

latch.await();


// And in your Callable:
class FileReader implements Callable {
File file
String param
FileReader(File file, String param){
    this.file = file
    this.param = param
}

public Object call() {
    try {
    LOG.info("Processing file" + filePath)
    ConfigInfo configInfo = new ConfigInfo()
    configInfo.setFilePath(filePath);
    configInfo.setReaderUid(readerUid);
    configInfo.setPatternsMap(patternsMap);
    new LogfileDataProcessor(configObject, param).processFileContent();
    } finally {
        latch .countDown();
    }
}
```

You can pass latch into thread as constructor arguments.

Comment: thanks a million for helping me out. The countdown latch did the trick  :-)  Now the program is working fine.

Comment: Just think - there can be better solution: you are using ExecutroService, so after submiting you can call pool.shutdown(); and wait for threads to be finished: pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES); Think it will be simplest implementation without additional latches

Comment: yeah. That too is working in the same way. Thanks for the information.

Comment: You can also (after calling `pool.shutdown()`) do `pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)` to wait forever (see [evaluation section here](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6179024))

Comment: @tim_yates: that was my previous comment actually

Comment: @alexey28 You showed setting a fixed timeout of 10 minutes.  I showed how to wait forever...

Comment: Wait forever was the one needed. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how do you know that only a few lines in your `call` method are executed but not all of them ? The only way I see that happening with the code you posted is that the creation of that `ConfigInfo` object would throw an exception.

I tried reproducing the scenario you are describing, but I only managed to get my program to exit if in the `Callable` I off-loaded the work to a new daemon `Thread`. See below for my SSCCE. Depending on whether you leave the `thread.setDaemon( true );` call in it the program finishes nicely after all `Thread`s are executed or finishes before any output is written to the console.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ExecutorServiceDemo {
  private static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 5 );

  private static void createAndExecuteThreads(){
    for( int i =0; i< 5; i++ ){
      pool.submit( new DummyCallable( "Callable " + i ) );
    }
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    createAndExecuteThreads();
    pool.shutdown();
  }
  private static class DummyCallable implements Callable<Object>{
    private final String message;

    private DummyCallable( String amessage ) {
      message = amessage;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
      Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {
            Thread.sleep( 5000 );
            System.out.println( "message = " + message );
          } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      };
      Thread thread = new Thread( runnable );
      thread.setDaemon( true );
      thread.start();
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

Is it possible you do something similar in your `new LogfileDataProcessor(configObject, param).processFileContent()` method ?

Comment: The scenario is the very same. For the question asked first the "processFileContent()" method has an HTTP post which was not working. Now the program is fine. Appreciating your help. Thanks :)